TemplateRef in Angular 18 missing context
What am I missing here? The template seems to render but the context is empty, resulting in just an empty button being displayed. Written with Angular 18.
import { AfterViewInit, Component, ElementRef, inject, TemplateRef, ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-template-ref',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [],
  template:`
  <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="theTemplateReference; context: context">
    Template not rendered
  </ng-container>
 
  <ng-template #theActualTemplate let-templateTitle="title" let-action="someMethod">
    <h2>{{templateTitle}}</h2>
    <button (click)="action(templateTitle)"></button>
  </ng-template>
  `,
  styleUrl: './template-ref.component.scss'
})
export class TemplateRefComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild({required: true}) theTemplateReference!: TemplateRef<ElementRef>;
  vcr = inject(ViewContainerRef);
  context = {
    title: 'templateRef Title',
    someMethod(title: string) {
      alert(`Alert for ${title}`);
    }
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log(this.theTemplateReference);
    this.vcr.createEmbeddedView(this.theTemplateReference);
  }

}


I guess, the main issue here is , you need to use @ViewChild , not @Input:
@ViewChild('theActualTemplate', { read: TemplateRef }) theActualTemplate: TemplateRef<HTMLElement>;

You should pass in the extra two arguments required for createEmbeddedView:
The second argument is the context and the third argument is an object, in which we can send the injector, this is good, when there are components inside the templateRef and can solve Dependency injection problems inside the template.
ngAfterViewInit() {
  console.log(this.theActualTemplate);
  this.vcr.createEmbeddedView(this.theActualTemplate, this.context, {
    injector: this.injector,
  });
}

Full Code:
import {
  AfterViewInit,
  Component,
  ElementRef,
  inject,
  TemplateRef,
  ViewContainerRef,
  Input,
  ViewChild,
  Injector,
} from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  imports: [CommonModule],
  template: `
    <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="theActualTemplate; context: context">
      Template not rendered
    </ng-container>
  
    <ng-template #theActualTemplate let-templateTitle="title" let-action="someMethod">
      <h2>{{templateTitle}}</h2>
      <button (click)="action(templateTitle)">button</button>
    </ng-template>
  `,
})
export class App {
  @ViewChild('theActualTemplate') theActualTemplate!: TemplateRef<any>;
  // @Input({required: true}) theTemplateReference!: TemplateRef<ElementRef>;
  vcr = inject(ViewContainerRef);
  injector = inject(Injector);
  context = {
    title: 'templateRef Title',
    someMethod(title: string) {
      alert(`Alert for ${title}`);
    },
  };

    ngAfterViewInit() {
      console.log(this.theActualTemplate);
      this.vcr.createEmbeddedView(this.theActualTemplate, this.context, {
        injector: this.injector,
      });
    }
}

bootstrapApplication(App);

Stackblitz Demo
